# I'm a complete beginner, how can i fix my python while loop code?

Tags: python

```
age = ''
while age != '100':
    print('please type your age')
    age = input()
    print('thank you, now i know you are' age )
```

I get errors on line 5.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: "I get errors on line 5"—what do they say? Please always share error messages. They aren't there for fun; they contain useful information.

Answer (score 2):

#### You have to include the `age` variable with a comma:

```
age = ''
while age != '100':
    print('please type your age')
    age = input()
    print('thank you, now i know you are', age)
```

You have to add the comma to tell python that you are adding something to the print statement

#### Another option is using f-strings

```
age = ''
while age != '100':
    print('please type your age')
    age = input()
    print(f'thank you, now i know you are {age}')
```

Comment: why not concatenate?

Comment: You could, but I wanted to include a easy solution, because the asker is a beginner

Comment: @Ade_1 Asking "why not" implies that concatenation is superior. Is it? How so?

Comment: @JohnKugelman oh no in terms  of superiority, but in relation to what the was trying to achieve. thats all

Answer (score 1):

Print formatted.

```
print(f'thank you, now i know you are {age}' )
```

Or

```
print('thank you, now i know you are {}'. format(age) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a comma in your final print statement so the interpreter knows that you are adding a second argument. Like this:

```
age = ''
while age != '100':
    print('please type your age')
    age = input()
    print('thank you, now i know you are', age)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
print('thank you, now i know you are' age )
```

try using

```
print(f'thank you, now i know you are {age}')
```

using f string is much better option.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on HackDolphin's answer, another option is to use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting), You can insert variables into a string and python will evaluate it when printing.

```
 age = ''
    while age != '100':
        print('please type your age')
        age = input()
        print(f'thank you, now i know you are {age}')
```